# merging multipe css pseudo classes

Tags: css

What I am trying to achieve is the following behavior,
I want the border of an input field in a form, to change color when:

1. it's not currently focused

and

2. it has a valid value

and

3. it isn't empty
   my current css looks like this:

```css
    input:not(:focus):valid:not(:empty) {
        border: 1.5px solid rgb(21, 215, 31);
    }
```

this code is not achieving the intended behavior, what could be the issue?

Comment: empty does't work the way you want. It considers elements that don't contain any HTML content, not input elements with empty field

Comment: maybe this is what you looked for ? https://mfl5fv.csb.app/

Comment: i made a small codesandbox example in the provided link tell me if that answer your questions please